# Can I detect h264 support in code?

Tags: video, h.264

For an installer I'm building, I need to be able to warn the user if they don't have an h264 codec installed.  At this point in the process I don't have any such video to play or anything, I just need to detect the ability to do so. Is this possible?

Unfortunately I can't rely on the computer having anything much already installed, such as .Net or DirectX (other than whatever comes with plain Windows XP or later).  The installer is written in C++.

Comment: Apologies!  Just after asking this question I realised that I don't actually need to detect this, as I'm already checking for Flash being installed, and Flash includes an H264 codec (at least it does in the versions I'm requiring)

Oops :)

Comment: You can post that as an answer to your own question. It's good for those who might Google your question later.

Comment: @Thanatos, "I guess I don't need the answer to this question" isn't a very helpful answer..

Comment: @Brendan Long: Huh? He answered it, more or less, above in the comment.

Comment: @Thanatos: The question is "how do I detect h264", "I don't actually need to detect h264" doesn't answer that.

Comment: I could 'answer' the question, but its still a useful question to ask, and if someone does have a real answer to it, it might be useful for later generations to have a record of their wisdom...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-26145.html), you can do this by either querying the registry (`\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Drivers32\vidc*`), or with DirectShow (probably better). The post by Toff on the page I linked to shows the DirectShow version.

Comment: You really don't want to do the drivers32 thingy.  That enumerates ACM codecs and I seriously doubt that anyone's going to write an ACM codec for h.264.  Use DShow to enumerate the codecs, and use MediaFoundation to enumerate them (for Vista and beyond).